# Animation won't play when button clicked

Tags: animation, lua, roblox

```lua
local button = game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.ImageButton
 
local AnimationController = script.Parent.AnimationController
local Animation = script.Animation
local animTrack = AnimationController:LoadAnimation(Animation)

local function PlayAnimation()
    print("hi")
    animTrack:Play()
end

button.MouseButton1Click:connect():Connect(PlayAnimation)
```

The print is not working so I assume it's either the mousebutton1click is not working or the function is not connecting that is the first problem, the second is I have tried to start getting into animation and I could use some tips for animation of models that are moving cause of an event.

I tried changing some of the variables but that has not worked, I have tried writing it different, not working, tried chatGPT kinda helped, tried getting errors in the output with the print but that hasn't printed anything, I think cause of the connection to the gui button, that is all I can think of right now.
If you can help I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely that the button you are clicking on isn't the one that you've connected your event to.

```lua
local button = game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.ImageButton
```

When a player's character spawns, the contents of the StarterGui are cloned into the player's PlayerGui. That means that the button you are clicking on needs a different path. Try this :

```lua
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local button = player.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.ImageButton
```